# Hiding div class with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wanting to have checkboxes hide and show a div class.

So far i have the code hiding the div but not showing it. Which i know i've done wrong somehow! i do have multiple checkboxes

heres my code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function show(target) {
  document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
}

function hide(target) {
  document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
}
    </script>
    <tr>
    <th><input onclick="hide('tester')" type="checkbox" checked>
```

I know its something to do with the onclick hide. Would it be better to have it as a toggle?

Sam

Comment: I don't see where you are calling the `show()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a single handler in which based on the checked state you can set the display value like

```js
function showhide(el, target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = el.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<input onclick="showhide(this, 'tester')" type="checkbox" checked />
<div id="tester">tester</div>
```

---

Using jQuery

```js
$('#mycheckbox').change(function() {
  $('#tester').toggle(this.checked)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" checked />
<div id="tester">tester</div>
```

Comment: @akash your code is in a dom ready handler... so it is not available in the global scope - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qvmjznam/2/ - in the left panel select `in head/body`

Comment: Thanks by the way +rep and will accept in 8 mins :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
    function toggle(target) {
    
      if(document.getElementById(target).style.display=="block")
      document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';        
      else
         document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<input onclick="toggle('toggle')" type="checkbox" checked>
<div id="toggle">Show and hide</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
var thumbsUp = element(by.css('span.glyphicon-thumbs-up'));
var thumbsDown = element(by.css('span.glyphicon-thumbs-down'));

it('should check ng-show / ng-hide', function() {
  expect(thumbsUp.isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();
  expect(thumbsDown.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();

  element(by.model('checked')).click();

  expect(thumbsUp.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
  expect(thumbsDown.isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();
});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/U0YybTyJK95ygR1r8nsb?p=preview)